# Prove that for any integer n, we have $n^3=n \text{ in }\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that for any integer $n$, we have $n^3=n  \text{ in } Z_6$

Comment: Yes, what did you try? (It's also rather easy to just test all six cases one-by-one.)

Comment: $$n^3-n=(n+1)n(n-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\displaystyle n^3-n = 6 \binom{n+1}{3} $.

Comment: Very nice hint !